# css issue causing right margin / gap / scroll in mobile view

Tags: css, mobile, scroll, overflow, margin

Totally baffling me...

http://www.fastnetwebdesign.co.uk

I have a right margin/gap/scroll in mobile view. Mainly seen in mobile (iPhone) browsers.

To see the right gap, disable `overflow-x: hidden;` on the body tag - you'll then see a black gap if you scroll to the right.

I know I am missing some simple css somewhere, but can't find where.

Comment: Try adding `box-sizing: border-box;` on your elements, that you think are causing the margin. it could fix your problem.

Comment: mmm... that doesn't resolve the issue

Comment: allright. You could also try to set a max-width on you body, to see if that fixes it.

Comment: thats messes up my layout... to see the right gap, disable overflow-x: hidden; on the body tag - you'll then see a black gap if you scroll to the right.